# How to copy one textbox value to another textbox in asp.NET gridview using javascript?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am not able copy or automatically bind into the second textbox. Which event do i need to handle, `onkeyup` or `onblur`?

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function OneTextToother()   
    { 
    var first=document.getElementById(txtQuantity).value;    
    document.getElementById(txtQuantity1).value=first; 
    }     
</script>

<asp:GridView ID="gvOrder" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvOrder_RowDataBound">       
<Columns>              
<asp:TemplateField>                   
<ItemTemplate>                    
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" onkeyup="javascript:OneTextToother();" >
</asp:TextBox>                    
</ItemTemplate>                                
</asp:TemplateField>     
<asp:TemplateField>                  
<ItemTemplate>                
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>               
</ItemTemplate>                              
</asp:TemplateField>          
</Columns>        
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Client Id property`

```
<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).FindControl("txtQuantity1").ClientID %>
```

So

```
var first = document.getElementById('<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).FindControl("txtQuantity").ClientID %>');

document.getElementById('<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).FindControl("txtQuantity1").ClientID %>').value=first;
```